# retrieve values from database using Id in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, controller, repository, store

I want to retrieve particular values from database using Id..

**Orgvasplans**

Id

vasplanId

orgId

createdDate

**vasplans**

Id

Name

Amount

Validity

The "vasplans" table values are already stored in database.. when I click button, it is automatically taken value from vasplans table and store into orgvasplans table. Also created date will store..

In view, it will retrieve the values from orgvasplans table... But I have problem with **vasplanId**. can anyone please check and tell me?

Comment: "it is showing an error.." what is the error?

Comment: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception "for details." and Plan id is showing 0.. In vasplans there is two id is created.. but still showing 0.